# Extracting "Initial Catalog" From a Connection String in SSIS 2008

Tags: regex, ssis

Hi Can anyone help me with a Regular expression to extract the value of Initial Catalog from a Connection String ?

```
  'Data Source=server\instance;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True'
```

I want to extract 'MyDatabase' from the connection string

```
   Catalog=(?s)(.*);
```

Using above mentioned Expression. I want only the Database name. How can i make it ignore Catalog and ; at the end and any possible blank spaces

Comment: Your question first off doesn't contain enough information for someone to be able to answer it (what connection string?) and secondly does not show any of your own efforts to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to have the package inspect itself during execution to identify the `Initial Catalog` value or are you trying to grep through the .dtsx file and extracting the value?

Comment: Connection string is stored in a Variable and i need to extract "Initial Catalog" from it on Run time inside a For-Each Loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SSIS Expression you can use in another variable to extract the Initial Catalog name.

```
SUBSTRING ( 
    SUBSTRING (  
        @[User:Connstring], 
        FINDSTRING (  
            @[User:Connstring],
            "Initial Catalog=",
            1),
        LEN (  @[User:Connstring])
    ),
    17,
    FINDSTRING ( 
        SUBSTRING (  
            @[User:Connstring],
            FINDSTRING (
                @[User:Connstring],
                "Initial Catalog=",
                1
            ),
            LEN ( @[User:Connstring])
        ),
        ";",
        1
    )  
    - 17
)
```

Comment: Yes, yes, SSIS Expression tools are awful.